# Bibliography for the Quantization of the free electromagnetic field with the Lorenz gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge

Recently I have been studying QFT and when I arrived at the Gauge theory I learned that one can quantize the electromagnetic field with the Coulomb gauge and the Lorenz gauge.

Regarding the Coulomb, I have found a lot of sources and the detailed process to do this, but for the Lorenz gauge, I have not found anything good. If anyone has any source that explains the quantization process with the Lorenz gauge in detail, I would appreciate it so much.